# System.out.println Printing itself when printing

Tags: java, android, arraylist, system.out

I'm working with a list and I am trying to print the contents to see if I am getting the result that I need. But when I `println` it, the `System.out.println` prints itself in it's own print (see below)

```
09-08 12:18:23.482    7718-7718/com.example I/System.out﹕ IMAGES are: [
09-08 12:18:23.482    7718-7718/com.example I/System.out﹕ [ 09-08 12:18:23.482 7718: 7718 I/System.out ]
__,__IwjV3bxFh7ADUCcZFCLsczmadO90TKeg.jpg
09-08 12:18:23.482    7718-7718/com.example I/System.out﹕ [ 09-08 12:18:23.482  7718: 7718 I/System.out ]
__,__CmonqJYgM8hiy4mHU9UmWDbNNbI4jjcb.jpg,
09-08 12:18:23.482    7718-7718/com.example I/System.out﹕ [ 09-08 12:18:23.482  7718: 7718 I/System.out ]
__,__AonUsfgTZpcdHUg4njUtExFC53E6IKRq.jpg, , , ]
```

Here is the code where I print the list:

```
final List<String> images = db.getAPIImages();
    for (String e : images){
        System.out.println("IMAGES are: " + e);
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is just an issue with Android Studio, but when I look in my db, the `System.out.println` isn't being stored so I believe it's just a print issue. I'd greatly appreciate some help.

**USING Log.d**

When using Log.d, I get the following output:

```
09-08 12:29:15.925  13757-13757/com.example D/IMAGES are:﹕ [
n8iQYdmU4HQkVJRTvgJfen7I8mUZ7oWW.jpg
poCcNRCTKeVtxbmyGiIaq5OfFg3b5Vce.jpg, , , , ]
```

From looking at that, I'm guessing a new line character is present between the two jpgs. How can I test for that and replace with a ","?

Comment: how about using [Log.d](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) ?

Comment: I updated my answer with that.

Comment: `System.out` is the name of the output stream, and not the name of the java method

Comment: Your `System.out` output is captured by a logger (that used `System.setOut`) that prints time and class too. If that logger again uses a console handler, it outputs to the real, original System.out.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint and check that the output from Log.d matches perfectly the String that you want to print. If that is fine, then I guess this question is to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including `temp1.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"),` has fixed my problem. Here is the full code:

```
for (String e : images){
        String temp = e.replaceFirst(strSeparator, "");
        String temp1 = temp.replace(strSeparator, ", ");
        String temp2 = temp1.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
        System.out.println("IMAGES are: " + temp2);
    }
```